# How do you pin gradients to a certain GPU in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I created a model with an embedding layer on CPU, an LSTM on gpu:0 and a softmax layer on gpu:1.

I then created a training op like so:

```
optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
train_op = optim.minimize(final_loss)
```

Training fails with an Out of Memory error. Enabling device placement logging reveals that the gradient for the softmax has been placed on gpu:0 rather than gpu:1. How can get TensorFlow to place it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place the gradients on the same device as the original (forward-pass) op, you should pass the optional argument `colocate_gradients_with_ops=True` to [`optim.minimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize). Your code will look like:

```
optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
train_op = optim.minimize(final_loss, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that option in the documentation.